# Use while loop to check a number between two other numbers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, data-structures, while-loop

I am generating some random number and want to check if this number is between n and m.
so the random number will be like,

```
r=random.randint(x,y)
```

now I want to check if r is between n and m and if it's between n and m then break the loop as I am using while loop for it

I am trying something like this,

```
r=0
while r>n & r<m:
    r=random.randint(x,y)
print(r)
```

But it's not working, not sure where I am doing wrong, looking for the solution using while loop

Comment: `&` is bitwise and in python. Try using `and`. Also note, `r` starts at `0`...it needs to be with the range to even *start* the loop.

Comment: and is also not giving desired result @Mark

Comment: You should show the values you are using for the variables otherwise it's hard to debug.

Comment: Why not just use `return random.randint(n, m)`? `randint` already does what you want.

Comment: This is a small part of a big problem, I cannot use random.randint(n, m) @Nick

Comment: Is this a part of a function? Otherwise `return` will not work.

Comment: @Mark r=0 as r is not between n and m, the loop will break when r is between n and m

Comment: Well you probably want `r < n or r > m` then, and for your `return r` to be outside your loop. But this whole question reeks of misunderstanding, or not actually knowing what you want, and your reasoning for not just using `random.randint(n + 1, m - 1)` makes zero sense.

Comment: @Nick correct, ..

Comment: @Kallol if `0` is not between n and m, the loop will never start, which mean r will stay at `0`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your while condition and on the position of the return statement.

First, if `n` is a positive number, then it will skip the while due to the assignment `r=0` (since `r` is smaller than `n`, the condition is false). If you want to break the loop when r is INSIDE the range, the condition must be false when r is inside the range.

Second, since the `return r` is inside the while, it will return something on the first iteration. The return should be after the while.

Try the following:

```
r=0
while !(r>n and r<m):
    r=random.randint(x,y)
return r
```

Answer (score 0):

```
r=0
while r>n & r<m:
    r=random.randint(x,y)
    return r
```

In this case, the while loop will only start if m>0>n (which is an easier way of writing this)
try something like this:

```
from random import randint
r=0
m=5
n=-5
while m>r>n:
    r=randint(-10,10)
print(r)
```